# Find the number of real solutions of the equation $f(f(x))$=4

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

Consider the graph of a real-valued continuous function $f(x)$ defined on $R$(the set of all real numbers) as shown below:
[image]

### Find the number of real solutions of the equation $f(f(x))=4.$

I found $f(x)=2x+8,\text{when} x\leq -2$
$f(x)=-2x,\text{when} -2<x\leq-1$
$f(x)=2x+4,\text{when} -1<x\leq0$
$f(x)=4-x,\text{when} 0<x\leq 2$
$f(x)=x,\text{when} 2<x\leq 4$
$f(x)=-4x+20,\text{when} x>4$
I tried to find the composition of the piecewise defined function.But i could not find $f(f(x))$
Please help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hints:

- If $f(y)=4$, what can $y$ be?
- If $f(z)=y$ where $f(y)=4$, what can $z$ be?
- If $f(f(x))=4$, how many possible values of $x$ are there?

Reading off the graph may help.

Comment: $f(f(x))=4$ when $f(x)=-2,0,4$,when $f(x)=-2$,then $x=-5,\frac{11}{2}$,when $f(x)=0$,then $x=-4,5$,when $f(x)=4$,then $x=-2,0,4$.So in all the seven solutions of the $f(f(x))$ are $x=-5,\frac{11}{2},-4,5,-2,0,4$.Have i got it correct,Sir@Henry

Comment: @diya: I get seven solutions too

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the graph treating $u$ as a dummy variable we see:

$f(u)=4$ for $u=-2,0,4$

Therefore we need to find values of $x$ s.t:

$u=f(x)=-2,0,4$

This happens $7$ times.